# Pass an event to a background view

Tags: ios, events, uiview, uiscrollview, touch

I have two views one `UIView` and the other `UIScrollView`. The `UIScrollView` is transparent and it is on top of `UIView`. I have buttons on `UIView`. I want to transfer vents like **Touch Up Inside** to the `UIView`.

thanks

Comment: in other word how to transfer event from one sub-view to another sub-view

Answer (score 0):

go to xib file ...click on identity inspector on the right-top corner,click on the third button,now select a uicontrol class from drop down list

Comment: I don't use Interface builder or Storyboard